# Excel VBA look for values in other sheet and copy them

Tags: vba, excel, copy, formula

I have two excel sheets: "Sheet1" and "Sheet2".

Sheet1 contains 3 columns with an N number of rows.
Example:

```
x     y     result

A     b
B     m
L     a
A     b
B     b
```

Sheet2 contains 3 columns as well but with the result as an explanation for each x and y combination.

Example:

```
x     y      result

A     a        1
A     b        2
A     c        3
B     a        4
```

Please note that A != a, and result is not always a numeric value.

**So basically I need to search Sheet2 for a given combination from values of Sheet1 and copy the result from Sheet2 to Sheet1.**

Can you give me example of VBA code how to achieve this?
Probably It's even possible with an Excel formula? Probably INDEX and MATCH? Anyhow, I can't figure this out by myself.

Thanks

Comment: Is my quesstion clear? Or I need to add any more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using formula itself. In your sheet1, please paste the below formula in C2 cell.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((--EXACT(Sheet2!A:A,A2))*(--EXACT(Sheet2!B:B,B2))*(--(Sheet2!A:A<>""))*(--(Sheet2!B:B<>"")),ROW(Sheet2!A:A))=0,"",INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,SUMPRODUCT((--EXACT(Sheet2!A:A,A2))*(--EXACT(Sheet2!B:B,B2))*(--(Sheet2!A:A<>""))*(--(Sheet2!B:B<>"")),ROW(Sheet2!A:A))))
```

and copy the same to other cells. It would work.

Please check the below images:

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

Comment: Yes tested this. Is your sheet names are correct? Values are in the same column as u described in the problem?

Comment: it just says that formula is not correct and highlights A,A2 part

Comment: I checked again, this command definitely works fine. Check the images that are added for your reference. Try to create something similar to that without missing any character from the above formula.  Then, can you please ensure that you first have both Sheet1 and Sheet2 created in your excel and then ensure that you copy the full formula and paste it without missing any characters from the above post?  And this formula has to be pasted in Sheet1 and the cell C2. Please let me know, which version of Excel that you are using if you still face any problem.

Comment: It works now! The problem was that I have a semicolon as formula separator, for example - my formulas should look like =EXACT(value1;value2), so I replaced "," to ";" and it works now! Thank you!

Comment: Can you please explain me the formula, so I can later adjust it for similar problems?

Comment: SUMPRODUCT((--EXACT(Sheet2!A:A,A2))*(--EXACT(Sheet2!B:B,B2))‌​*(--(Sheet2!A:A<>"")‌​)*(--(Sheet2!B:B<>""‌​)),ROW(Sheet2!A:A)) is the major part, which helps to find the row number of matching criteria. The index function, just gives the value of the specified row from the given range. The 'if'  part is included to display empty string if the record is not found.

Answer (score 0):

First add another column containing a formula to create a unique key:

```
Sheet1:
   A       B       C       D
1  x       y       result  key 
2  A       b               =A2&B2
3  B       m               =A3&B3
4  L       a               =A4&B4
etc...

Sheet2:
   A       B       C       D     
1  x       y       result  key
2  A       a       1       =A2&B2
3  A       b       2       =A3&B3
4  A       c       3       =A4&B4
etc...
```

Then try this:

```
Sub FindResult()

Dim XY As String
Dim S1 As Object, S2 As Object
Dim ResultCell As Range, ResultValue As String

    Set S1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set S2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Calculate
    For Rr = 2 To 6
        XY = S1.Cells(Rr, 4).Value
        Set ResultCell = S2.Range("D:D").Find( _
                                              What:=XY, _
                                              After:=S2.Range("D1"), _
                                              LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                              LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                              SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                              MatchCase:=True, _
                                              SearchFormat:=False _
                                             )
        If ResultCell Is Nothing Then
            ResultValue = "Not found"
        Else
            ResultValue = ResultCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End If
        S1.Cells(Rr, 3) = ResultValue
    Next Rr

End Sub
```